# how to display label and values only on google pie chart legend with data from mysql db

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, pie-chart

I am using google charts API to display pie chart and I want the legend to display only the label and values and I'm stucked, most of the answers I searched includes percentage. How can I do this?

My code below:

**PHP**

```
$table         = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
    //Labels for the chart, these represent the column titles
    array('id' => '', 'label' => 'Country', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('id' => '', 'label' => 'Number of Devices', 'type' => 'number')
); 

$rows = array();
foreach($exec as $row){
    $temp = array();

    //Values
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $row['Country']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $row['Number of Devices']); 
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

$table['rows'] = $rows; 
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
echo $jsonTable
```

**JavaScript**

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var PieChart_options = {
      title: 'Number of Devices per country',
      pieSliceText: 'value',
      width: 900, 
      height: 500
    };

 var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('pie_div'));
  chart.draw(data, PieChart_options);

}
```

I want to create like this one:
[pie chart with label and value on legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECTL2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the chart can be modified, once the `'ready'` event fires

be sure to set the event listener, before drawing the chart

the legend labels should appear in the same order as the data provided

the following snippet finds the legend labels by checking attribute values

then adds the value from the data...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
      "cols": [
        {"label": "Country", "type": "string"},
        {"label": "# of Devices", "type": "number"}
      ],
      "rows": [
        {"c": [{"v": "Canada"}, {"v": 33}]},
        {"c": [{"v": "Mexico"}, {"v": 33}]},
        {"c": [{"v": "USA"}, {"v": 34}]}
      ]
    });

    var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(container);

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
      var rowIndex = 0;
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('text'), function(label) {
        // find legend labels
        if ((label.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'start') && (label.getAttribute('fill') !== '#ffffff')) {
          label.innerHTML += ' (' + data.getValue(rowIndex++, 1) + ')';
        }
      });
    });

    chart.draw(data, {
      height: 400,
      width: 600
    });
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome! can you please explain that if condition ?@whitehat

Comment: sure, the `if` statement is used to separate the `'text'` elements for the legend labels from the pie slice labels. it just says, find the labels where the attribute for `'text-anchor'` is equal to `'start'` _and_ the attribute for `'fill'` (color) is not `'#ffffff'`(white) -- i used the elements tab in the developer's tools of my browser to investigate the attributes of each. if you change the position of the legend, you may need to change the if statement for `'text-anchor'` to `'middle'` or `'end'` -- or if you change the slice text color, you would need to change the `'fill'` test as well

Comment: where can i learn these things its not in the google docs ryt? @WhiteHat

Comment: this website is a good place to start -- but basically code and code some more, it can take a while but you pick up things here and there along the way -- this answer just boils down to using the browser's developer's tools to inspect the dom after the chart has been drawn -- if it exists in the dom, it can be modified with script

Answer (score 1):

**Simply**, Just format the data from mysql like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/AravindhGopi/prsadtrk/3/)

```
 ['Work (11)',     11]
```

It won't *affect* your chart though.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the answer I need is how to put the value beside the label in legend not on the pie slice. 

like in this example
http://codepen.io/breich/pen/mVPJwo

Comment: I want is like the link I give above, and using that codes doesn't give me the same result